# Matlab: Website with a lot of functions to download

Tags: functions, math-software, matlab

I am looking for a website that contains a collection of functions, more than Matlab contains, to download I use from Matlab. 
The extension should be *.m or the code should appear.
Thank you!

Comment: Is there any specific kind of functions you're looking into? What's wrong with the plenty of Matlab packages?

Comment: You probably had [this](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/) in mind.

Answer (score 2):

How about the MATLAB Central [File Exchange](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/)?